# Plot data and quantity

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have this df of NY airbnb house, the full data set is available at [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data#AB_NYC_2019.csv).

[image: the dataframe]

This is my code in which I get

- the number_of_reviews (in a specific price range and distance from Wall Street)
- the dates of latest reviews

I merged this two and sorted descending. Then I get the 10 max values.

```
df = pd.read_csv("df.csv", index_col='id')
df = df.dropna()

manhattan = df.loc[(df['neighbourhood_group'] == 'Manhattan') & (df['room_type'] == 'Entire home/apt')]

mn_location = 110 * (np.arccos(np.sin(manhattan['latitude']) * np.sin(40.7038)
                               + np.cos(manhattan['latitude']) * np.cos(40.7038)
                               * np.cos(-74.0057 - manhattan['longitude'])))
mn = manhattan.copy()
mn['mn_location'] = mn_location.round(decimals=1)

range2 = mn[(mn['mn_location'] <= 2) & (mn['price'] > 155) & (mn['price'] <= 160)]


pie = range2[['number_of_reviews', 'last_review']].sort_values(by=['number_of_reviews'], ascending=False).head(10)
```

I'd like to make a plot (hist, scatter... maybe a timeline) in which I have on the X axis the dates (last_review) and in Y axis the quantity (number_of_reviews).

Answer (score 0):

```
pie.plot.bar(x = 'last_review', y='number_of_reviews')
```